# Rename Columns of all Data Frames in Environment R

Tags: r, dplyr, quantmod, rbind

Looking for a way to rename columns of all data frames in my R environment.

I have 3 dataframes, which we can call a, b, and c with the respective column names:

```
# a
AMZN.Open AMZN.Close AMZN.Volume

#b
AAPL.Open AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume

#c
MSFT.Open MSFT.Close MSFT.Volume
```

I want to rename the columns of all the data frames to "Open", "Close", and "Volume" so they can be binded together (ideally in one call, and a solution robust enough to handle many more than just 3 environment objects).

Is there a way this can be applied?

Comment: You really should show he code used to create these. Your request risks elimination of identifiers for the data if you `rbind` them together. Best approach would be to start with code that leaves these separate dataframes in a single list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with `rename_with` and a user-defined function.

```
# Create example data frames
dat_a <- data.frame(AMZN.Open = NA, AMZN.Close = NA, AMZN.Volume = NA)
dat_b <- data.frame(AAPL.Open = NA, AAPL.Close = NA, AAPL.Volume = NA)
dat_c <- data.frame(MSFT.Open = NA, MSFT.Close = NA, MSFT.Volume = NA)

dat_list <- list(dat_a, dat_b, dat_c)

# Load the package
library(tidyverse)

# Define a function to rename the column names
col_fun <- function(x){
  y <- str_remove(x, pattern = ".*\\.")
  return(y)
}

# Apply the function with rename_with
dat_list2 <- map(dat_list, ~rename_with(.x, .fn = col_fun))

# Print the results
dat_list2
# [[1]]
# Open Close Volume
# 1   NA    NA     NA
# 
# [[2]]
# Open Close Volume
# 1   NA    NA     NA
# 
# [[3]]
# Open Close Volume
# 1   NA    NA     NA
```

**Update**

```
# Load the package
library(tidyverse)

# Extract the stock ticker
stock_ticker <- function(x){
  y <- str_extract(x, pattern = "^.*(?=\\.)")
  
  y <- unique(y)
  
  if (length(y) > 1){
    stop("More than one stock ticker")
  }
  
  return(y)
}

# Define a function to rename the column names
col_fun <- function(x){

  y <- str_remove(x, pattern = ".*\\.")
  
  return(y)
}


# Apply the function with rename_with and apply the sotck_ticker function
dat_list2 <- map(dat_list, function(x){
  col <- names(x)
  
  ticker <- stock_ticker(col)
  
  x2 <- x %>%
    rename_with(.fn = col_fun) %>%
    mutate(`Stock Ticker` = ticker)
  return(x2)
})
```

Comment: this works, but I have lost the Stock identifier in the process. Is there a way to convert the ticker part of the column names to a field? Ex: The result after using the function would return Open, Close, Volume, and Stock Ticker

Comment: @bodega18 Your example does not contain a Stock Ticker column, so I am not sure what do you mean. Perhaps you can post a new question, and this time with a reproducible example so others can help you. I will take a look if you do that.

Comment: the stock ticker precedes the “.” in each column name. For example with AMZN.Close, the ticker is AMZN, with MSFT.Close it is MSFT, etc. Apologies if that wasn’t the most clear